# Force children to take up same space yet start at 0, 0?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Consider a modal with tabs within, and tab content. The content of the first tab is 100px high, second is 500px, and 3rd is 50px. The goal is to have the modal body *always* be the height of the tallest tab (500px), so as you switch between tabs, the size of the modal remains constant.

This cannot be accomplished by:

- Setting the tab content area wrapper to `position: relative` and each tab to `position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;` because absolute-positioned elements don't take up space.
- Setting all tabs to be invisible by default, except for the active one which is visible. This causes tabs to stack vertically so tab two will have a 100px space above it and tab 3 will have a 600px space above it (overall height of the modal's body would be the height of all tabs combined).

See example linked below. Toggle between "End Goal" and "Actual" to see the visual difference and what I'm trying to accomplish.

I really don't want to have to use JS to check each tab's height (would need to be done at an interval as tabs can change height based on current selections, etc.). So that would be a pretty hacky solution. Not sure if there is a better way.

For now, I will pick a "good" height for the tab container and allow taller tabs to scroll if needed.

Example: https://codepen.io/joshm123/pen/NWrEVjJ (copied below)

**HTML**

```
<div class="modal">
  <div class="header">
    <h2>Welcome!</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="body">
    <div class="tabs">
      <button class="tab" onClick="selectTab(1)">Tab 1</button>
      <button class="tab" onClick="selectTab(2)">Tab 2</button>
      <button class="tab" onClick="selectTab(3)">Tab 3</button>
    </div>
    
    <div class="tabs-wrapper">
      <div id="tab1" class="tab-content active">
        blah blah blah<br/>
        blah blah blah
      </div>
      <div id="tab2" class="tab-content">
        blah blah blah<br/>
        blah blah blah<br/>
        blah blah blah<br/>
        blah blah blah<br/>
        blah blah blah<br/>
        blah blah blah<br/>
        blah blah blah<br/>
        blah blah blah<br/>
        blah blah blah<br/>
        blah blah blah
      </div>
      <div id="tab3" class="tab-content">
        blah blah blah
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <button id="showEndGoalButton" onClick="toggleView()">Show End Goal</button>
    <button id="showActualButton" onClick="toggleView()">Show Actual</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.modal {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  left: calc(50% - 250px);
  top: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}

.header {
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
}

.header h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.body {
  padding: 10px;
}

.tabs > .tab {
  margin-right; 10px;
}

.tabs-wrapper {
  margin: 10px 0;
  border: 1px dotted red;
}

.tab-content {
  visibility: hidden;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
}

.tab-content.active {
  visibility: visible;
}

.footer {
  padding: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid #999;
  text-align: right;
}

/* supporting CSS

    - height of tallest tab is 182px
    - make all tabs this hard-coded height
    - this is not a real solution, but an example
      what the end result should be (visually)
*/
.modal #showActualButton {
  display: none;
}

.modal.end-goal #showEndGoalButton {
  display: none;
}

.modal.end-goal #showActualButton {
  display: inline-block;
}

.modal.end-goal .tabs-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 182px;
}

.modal.end-goal .tab-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

**JS**

```
window.selectTab = function (num) {
  const tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.tab-content');
  const tab = document.querySelector(`#tab${num}`);
  
  tabs.forEach(o => o.classList.remove('active'));
  tab.classList.add('active');
}

window.toggleView = function() {
  document
    .querySelector('.modal')  
    .classList
    .toggle('end-goal');
}
```

Comment: Your [mcve] needs to be in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a simple tab panel, you can make a container with `overflow: hidden` and add an inner-container that is wider than that container. In your case, you have 3 tabs, so the inner-container should be `300%` wide.

This will allow the container to respect the tallest inner-div because it is essentially cropping the inner-container.

Then use javascript to adjust the `transform` on `.inner` to control which tab is being shown. I didn't write the javascript, but when "tab 1" is clicked, set `inner` div to `transform: translateX(0)`. When "tab 3" is clicked, `transform: translateX(-66.666%)` ... hopefully you get the ide.

```css
:root {
  --num-of-tabs: 3;
}

.container {
  width: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.inner {
  width: calc(var(--num-of-tabs) * 100%); 
  display: flex;
  transform: translateX(-33.33%); /* staring on tab #2 */
}

.box {
  width: calc(100% / var(--num-of-tabs));
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="box">
      blah blah blah
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      blah blah blah blah
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      blah blah blah<br/>
        blah blah blah<br/>
        blah blah blah<br/>
        blah blah blah<br/>
        blah blah blah<br/>
        blah blah blah<br/>
        blah blah blah<br/>
        blah blah blah<br/>
        blah blah blah<br/>
        blah blah blah
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sounds like it should work. I consider it a hack still, but there is no "non-hack" solution as far as I know. I like it. I think it can be done w/out JS at all. Thanks.

Comment: It might not be ideal for some use cases, but not really a hack imo. Glad it helps.

Comment: I ended up going with something similar. Thanks.